# Why is excel showing result as equal and double quote instead of the vlaue

Tags: excel, csv

'Here is the problem. I'm importing data from a csv file generate by a software. Instead of seeing the data like

Picute 1

[image: 1]

I want to see it has

picture 2

[image: 2]'

Comment: How does the data look in the CSV? Open in an editor like Notepad++.

Comment: like this   .... =""0090"""

Comment: So the software generating the CSV is adding an equal-sign as well as double-double-quoting stuff. Perhaps multiple ways around this and may depend on how you are importing into Excel. I would probably replace all equal signs with nothing, and replace all double-double quotes with a double-quote. Then import into Excel, making sure the column is formatted as Text to avoid losing the leading zeros.

Comment: That is what I'm doing via excel convert data. But I wanted to know if there was a more faster way because I can't change the way the csv is generated. It's generate from the CRM software, by click generate CSV. that is how much option I have hehe.  Thanks, so it's either format the CSV with Notepad++ or format it in excel with data convert. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can try not formatting the column as text.  Then copy paste the values in a text formatted column.

Comment: Looks like the CRM is outputting the function not the value. You might want to see if there is setting for the generate CSV to change that.